# asp.net GridView table does not sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

i have the  following asp grid control:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gwreportpub" CellPadding="5" AllowPaging="true" 
            runat="server" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" BackColor="White" Caption="" 
            AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="grdCause_Sorting" 
            BorderColor="MidnightBlue" 
            BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Navy" CssClass="mainBodyPosition" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E7E4DA" />

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F6F0" />

            </asp:GridView>
```

this is the c# code behind, the table show but the sorting dose not work, why ??

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;

 public partial class ShowReportPub : System.Web.UI.Page 
 {  
    private DB_Utility dbu;
    protected double size = 1;
    private string connectionString;
    private OracleConnection connection;
    private OracleCommand processNumQuery;
    private int indexdropitem;
    private int coloreriga = 1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {


    if (!IsPostBack)
         {
        Session["CONNECTSTRING"] = Request["CONNECTSTRING"];

        if (Session["CONNECTSTRING"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("sessionup.asp?type=ShowReportPub");
        }

        connectionString = Session["CONNECTSTRING"].ToString();

        if (connectionString.IndexOf("DSN=") >= 0)
        {
            Comuni.Utility util = new Utility();
            connectionString = util.ConnStr(connectionString);
            Session["CONNECTSTRING"] = connectionString;
        }
        connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        dbu = new DB_Utility(Session["CONNECTSTRING"].ToString());

         }
         else
         {
        connectionString = Session["CONNECTSTRING"].ToString();
        if (connectionString.IndexOf("DSN=") >= 0)
        {
            Comuni.Utility util = new Utility();
            connectionString = util.ConnStr(connectionString);
            Session["CONNECTSTRING"] = connectionString;
        }
        connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        dbu = new DB_Utility(Session["CONNECTSTRING"].ToString());
         }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
            //Response.Write("str :" + Request["param1"] + " - " + Request["param2"]);
            processNumQuery = new OracleCommand("select distinct nome_report from rpg_notification",connection);
            OracleDataReader reader = processNumQuery.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(0)));
            }
            reader.Close();

            //if(Request["param1"]!=""){
                //dropdownlist1.SelectedValue = Request["param1"];
            //}


    }
    if(Request["txtSchedDate"] == null)
    {

         //if(Request["param2"]!="")
            //txtSchedDate.Text = Request["param2"];
    }
    else
    {

         txtSchedDate.Text = Request["txtSchedDate"];
         gwreportpub.DataSource = getDatiFromDb();
         gwreportpub.DataBind();


    }

         }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
    string datarepo = "";
    if(Request["txtSchedDate"] != ""){
        DateTime schedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["txtSchedDate"]);
        datarepo = schedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

    string reportname = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text; 


    gwreportpub.DataSource = getDatiFromDb();
    gwreportpub.DataBind();
    gwreportpub.Visible = true;
    if (gwreportpub.Rows.Count == 0)
    {   
            tbnotif.Text = "Non vi sono report pubblicati";
            tbnotif.Visible = true;
    }
    else{
        tbnotif.Visible = true;
        tbnotif.Text = "Tabella dei Report Pubblicati: ";
    }
    return;


    }


    public DataSet getDatiFromDb()
    {
        DataSet dt;
        if(Request["txtSchedDate"] != ""){
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand orclc = new OracleCommand("select relco, data_report, data_pubblicazione,anno_competenza, mese_competenza, pubblicato, md5, nome_file, path from rpg_notification where pubblicato = :flag and data_report <= TO_DATE(:repdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') and nome_report = :nome order by data_pubblicazione desc ",this.connection);
            orclc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":flag", OracleType.VarChar));
            orclc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":nome", OracleType.VarChar));
            orclc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":repdate", OracleType.VarChar));
            orclc.Parameters[":flag"].Value = "Y";
            orclc.Parameters[":nome"].Value = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;
            orclc.Parameters[":repdate"].Value = Request["txtSchedDate"].ToString();

            adapter.SelectCommand = orclc;

            dt = new DataSet("rpg_notification");   
            adapter.Fill(dt,"rpg_notification");
        }
        else{
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommand orclc = new OracleCommand("select relco, data_report, data_pubblicazione,anno_competenza, mese_competenza, pubblicato, md5, nome_file, path from rpg_notification where pubblicato = :flag and nome_report = :nome order by data_pubblicazione desc ",this.connection);
            orclc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":flag", OracleType.VarChar));
            orclc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":nome", OracleType.VarChar));
            orclc.Parameters[":flag"].Value = "E";
            orclc.Parameters[":nome"].Value = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;

            adapter.SelectCommand = orclc;

            dt = new DataSet("rpg_notification");   
            adapter.Fill(dt,"rpg_notification");
        }
        return dt;
    }
     protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender,
     GridViewPageEventArgs e)
     {
         gwreportpub.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
         gwreportpub.DataBind();
     }


 protected void grdCause_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
    }


}
private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    //  You can cache the DataTable for improving performance
    gwreportpub.DataSource = getDatiFromDb().Tables[0];
    gwreportpub.DataBind();
    DataTable dt = gwreportpub.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

    gwreportpub.DataSource = dv;
    gwreportpub.DataBind();

}
private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";

public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Brian: "[...]Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary." :)

Comment: please any help ??? i can't make it work :(

Comment: why e.SortExpression is empty??

Comment: i did answer alone, thx to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the answer is this:

i had to change the control in this way:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gwreportpub" CellPadding="5" AllowPaging="true" OnRowDataBound="gvdetails_RowDataBound" 
            runat="server" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" BackColor="White" Caption="" 
            AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortRecords" 
            BorderColor="MidnightBlue" autogeneratecolumns = "False"
            BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Navy" CssClass="mainBodyPosition" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="False">

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E7E4DA" />

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F6F0" />
            <columns>
                <asp:boundfield datafield="societa_di_vendita" headertext="Societa di vendita"  sortexpression="societa_di_vendita" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="data_report" headertext="Data report" sortexpression="data_report" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="data_pubblicazione" headertext="Data di pubblicazione" sortexpression="data_pubblicazione" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="anno_competenza" headertext="Anno di competenza" sortexpression="anno_competenza" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="mese_competenza" headertext="Mese di competenza" sortexpression="mese_competenza" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="pubblicato" headertext="Pubblicato" sortexpression="pubblicato" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="err_pubblicazione" headertext="Errore di pubblicazione" sortexpression="err_pubblicazione" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="md5" headertext="Md5" sortexpression="md5" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="nome_file" headertext="Nome del file" sortexpression="nome_file" />
                <asp:boundfield datafield="path" headertext="Percorso" sortexpression="Percorso" />
           </columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

pay attention to the autogeneratecolumns  = "False" 
and to the columns, sorting names

after this i have used this 2 functions :

```
    public SortDirection SortDirection
{
get
{
    if (ViewState["SortDirection"] == null)
    {
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
    }
    return (SortDirection)ViewState["SortDirection"];
}
set
{
   ViewState["SortDirection"] = value;
}
}   

protected void SortRecords(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
  sortexpr = e.SortExpression;
  string direction = string.Empty;

  if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
  {
      SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
      direction = " DESC";
  }
  else
  {
     SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
     direction = " ASC";
  }
  //Response.Write("" + sortexpr +  " -.- " + direction);
  DataTable table = this.getDatiFromDb().Tables[0];
  table.DefaultView.Sort = sortexpr + direction;
  gwreportpub.DataSource = table;
  gwreportpub.DataBind();

}
```

everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 protected void grdCause_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        ViewState["sortExpr"] = sortExpression + DESCENDING;
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        ViewState["sortExpr"] = sortExpression  + ASCENDING;
    }

    SortGridView();
}
```

and

```
private void SortGridView()
{
    //  You can cache the DataTable for improving performance
    gwreportpub.DataSource = getDatiFromDb().Tables[0];
    gwreportpub.DataBind();
    if(ViewState["sortExpr"] != null){
      DataTable dt = gwreportpub.DataSource as DataTable;
      DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
      dv.Sort = (string)ViewState["sortExpr"];
    gwreportpub.DataSource = dv;
    gwreportpub.DataBind();
    }


}
```

Comment: gwreportpub.DataSource = dv;  dv is not declared where it is ?

Comment: thanks for the heads up :)! i forgot to put it inside the if statement

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the if statement in the function SortGridView(). Does it go inside the if statement after?

Comment: e.SortExpression is empty why??

Comment: Inside your gridview, do you have any templateField or BoundField with the "SortExpression" attribute? It is needed in order to sort.